# What is the correct terminology for Permutation & Combination formulae that allow repeating elements.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let me explain by example.

Q: Given four possible values, `{1,2,3,4}`, how many 2 value permutations are there ?

A: 16.

```
(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4)
(3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4)
(4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4)
```

However, running `4P2` through Wolfram Alpha gives me an answer of `12`.

Q: Similarly, given four possible values, `{1,2,3,4}`, how many 2 value combinations are there?

A: 10.

```
(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)
       (2,2), (2,3), (2,4)
              (3,3), (3,4)
                     (4,4)
```

However, running `4C2` through Wolfram Alpha gives me an answer of `6`.

I'm assuming because the implementations of `nCm` and `nPm` removed the element from the source set so it can't be chosen again. (similar to lottery balls picked from a drum).

Is there other terminology/formulae for the equivalent where it's possible to return each value. The real life situation would be dice-rolls, where all 6 options are still available on each subsequent roll of the dice.

Comment: Note: curly brackets are usually used to denote *sets*; in sets, order and repetition do not matter; that is, most mathematicians will see $\{1,4\}$ and $\{4,1\}$ and $\{1,1,4,4,4,4\}$ as representing the same object. If you want to take into account order, then one usually uses the "ordered tuple notation" which uses parentheses, not curly brackets.

Comment: They are called "combinations with repetitions" and "permtuations with repetitions". $\binom{n}{m}$ ($n$ choose $m$) counts the number of $m$-element subsets from a set of $n$ (distinct) elements; as I noted above, this does not take into account repetitions or order. $P^n_m$ (permutations) counts the number of $m$-length strings from an $n$-letter alphabet, without repetition allowed. To allow repetitions you need slightly different formulas.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin... mea culpa. Spot the programmer with array notation :-) I'll fix the formatting in the question to use `(` & `)`

Comment: Look also for *multiset* in Wikipedia.

Comment: If your set of values is S, and you want all n value permutations with repetition, create the cross-product of S for n times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/generating-permutations-with-repetitions-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In "permutations", the order matters. In "combinations", the order does not matter.

The basic rules of counting are the Product Rule and the Sum Rule. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11312/742), for example.

1. Permutations with repetitions allowed:

   If you have $n$ objects, and you want to count how many permutations of length $m$ there are: there are $n$ possibilities for the first term, $n$ for the second term, $n$ for the third term, etc. So the total number is $n^m$.
2. Permutations without repetitions allowed:

   If you have $n$ objects, and you want to count permutations of length $m$ with no repetitions (sometimes called "no replacement"): there are $n$ possibilities for the first term, $n-1$ for the second (you've used up one), $n-2$ for the third, etc. So the total number is
   $$P^n_m = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}.$$
3. Combinations without repetitions allowed:

   In combinations we don't care about the order. If you select $m$ objects from $n$ possibilities and they are all distinct, then there are $P^m_m = n!$ ways of ordering them. So if you count *permutations* instead, you will count each distinct choice of elements exactly $m!$ times. Therefore, $\binom{n}{m}$ (also denoted $nCm$, both read "$n$ choose $m$") is given by:
   $$\binom{n}{m} = \frac{1}{m!}P^n_m = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}.$$
4. Combinations with repetitions allowed:

   You have $n$ objects, and you want to select $m$ of them, allowing repetitions. To simplify things, let us assume our $n$ objects are precisely the numbers $1$, $2,\ldots,n$. Given a selection of $m$ objects with possible repetitions, $a_1,\ldots,a_m$, order them in ascending order, $a_1\leq a_2\leq\cdots\leq a_m$, and think of them as an $m$-tuple: $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)$. We want to count the number of such tuples with entries between $1$ and $n$, repetitions allowed.

   Let us associate to each such tuple an $m$-tuple with *no* repetitions and with entries between $1$ and $n+m-1$ as follows: given $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)$, with $1\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq\cdots\leq a_m\leq n$, we associate the tuple $(a_1,a_2+1,a_3+2,\ldots,a_m+m-1)$. Note that 
   $$1\leq a_1\lt a_2+1\lt\cdots \lt a_m+m-1\leq n+m-1.$$
   Conversely, given a tuple $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m)$ with $1\leq b_1\lt b_2\lt\cdots\lt b_m\leq n+m-1$, we have $b_i\geq n+i$; so this tuple "comes from" the tuple $(b_1,b_2-1,b_3-2,\ldots,b_m-m+1)$, which is a nondecreasing tuple with values between $1$ and $n$; i.e., it is one of our original $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$s.

   That means that counting the nondecreasing tuples $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)$ with $1\leq a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_m\leq n$ is equivalent to counting the number of strictly increasing tuples $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m)$ with $1\leq b_1\lt b_2\lt\cdots\lt b_m\leq n+m-1$. This is, in turn, equivalent to counting the number of ways of selecting $m$ objects from among $\{1,2,\ldots,n+m-1\}$, with no repetitions allowed. This is just $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$.

Answer (score 1):

nPm and nCm give you the number ways to choose two elements (in either case no element can be chosen twice). nPm cares about the order (so $(1,2)\neq(2,1)$), nCm does not. So the answers correclty are 12 and 6. What you want is just an exponential. For n distinct elements (4) forming a sequence of m elements (2), there are $m^n$ possible combinations (16).

Answer (score 1):

Formulae :

$n^k$ : number of permutations with repetition

$\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k! \cdot (n-1)!}$  :number of combinations with repetition

where $n$ is a number of elements of given set .

Comment: but the second formula is what I'm looking for. Thanks Pedja.

Comment: @EoinCampbell "trycatch.me" - excellent name for web site...